# Is there any way to use dropbox core api to send invites to share a folder in Python?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I am developing an app to retrieve and store files to dropbox using oauth2 protocol. Is there any way to use dropbox core api to send invites to share a folder in Python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Dropbox API currently doesn't expose any way to send shared folder invites. But a shared folder API is being worked on.

Comment: So is there any other way to achieve this? Either using POST method to send invites by getting the link to the folder.

Comment: No, there's no way to invite a user to a shared folder programmatically.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Is there any way to check if a given folder is shared with some other users or not. And if possible, finding all those users.

Comment: Until the shared folder API is built and released, there is no support in the API for shared folders (sending invitations, accepting invitations, finding out whom a folder is shared with, anything).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I wanted to know if there is any way to get email id of the user who has signed in using dropbox api.

Comment: That doesn't seem to relate to this question (or answer), so a comment here is inappropriate. Ask a new question!